# How to split a large file at a certain point into smaller ones?

Tags: perl, split

I'm having difficulty writing code to split a large text file that goes like this:

```
#Article:
ABC
DEF
#Article:
GHJ
KDJD
```

I want to split the file in chunks starting with `#Article` and save each chunk in text files named *output1*, *output2*, and so on.

So, for example:

```
#Article:
ABC
DEF
```

would be saved in a text file named *output1.txt*.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Since you are fairly new here, please take a [tour] and learn [ask] good questions. As a general rule, most people will not be very inclined to attempt to help you unless you've displayed some minimal effort in solving the problem on your own.

Answer (score -1):

Just reopen the output handle every time you encounter the header. As a one-liner:

```
perl -pe'
   if ($_ eq "#Article:\n") {
      open(STDOUT, ">", sprintf("output%d.txt", ++$count))
         or die $!;
   }
'
```

Usage:

```
perl -pe'...' input.txt     # Read from file(s) provided as arguments.
perl -pe'...' <input.txt    # Read from STDIN.
```